# EB Environment for multi-container docker is failed to be created

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm gonna set up sample `elasticbeanstalk` environment for `multi-container docker`.
But it is not created due to error.

environment tier: web-server
[other configuation info is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKwBn.png)

I want to create sample `elasticbeanstalk` environment for `multi-container docker`.
But the actual is not created.

```
ERROR   Creating Auto Scaling group named: awseb-e-at4dw9xg2u-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-11FLLBCSSSP3 failed.
        Reason: Group did not stabilize. {current/minSize/maxSize} group size = {0/1/1}. 
        Failed Scaling Activity: No default subnet for availability zone: 'ap-northeast-1c'. Launching EC2 instance failed.
ERROR   Stack named 'awseb-e-at4dw9xg2u-stack' aborted operation. 
        Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBAutoScalingGroup].
```

Comment: As the error says `Failed Scaling Activity: No default subnet for availability zone: 'ap-northeast-1c'. Launching EC2 instance failed` You don;t have any default subnet for `ap-northeast-1c` az. You need to specify subnet explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for reply. this error is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As @ mchawre suggested on comment, I resolved this issue

````
Failed Scaling Activity: No default subnet for availability zone: 'ap-northeast-1c'. Launching EC2 instance failed You don;t have any default subnet for ap-northeast-1c```
````